# Woocommerce filter text width

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have started to design a new site to my cousins and decided to use woocommerce as filter options is what we need. All products shall be filtered by their attributes. I put woocommerce filter widget on sidebar. But the text in the dropdown is not a single line in one attribute. It is on 2 line even it is a short attribute.

[Shows where this issue occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhkL2.png)

I have realized that all 3 filters have different width in the style;

```
<span class="widgetSelect dropdown_layered_nav_tamirci" style="display: inline-block;">
<span class="widgetSelectInner" style="width: 225px; display: inline-block;">Hangi Tamirci</span>
</span>


<span class="widgetSelect dropdown_layered_nav_sehir" style="display: inline-block;">
<span class="widgetSelectInner" style="width: 73px; display: inline-block;">Hangi Şehir</span>
</span>

<span class="widgetSelect dropdown_layered_nav_ilce" style="display: inline-block;">
<span class="widgetSelectInner" style="width: 77px; display: inline-block;">Hangi İlçe</span>
</span>
```

I found in woocomerce plugin "wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/widgets" class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php file has something but I couldnt manage to figure it out.

I have added below code but it didn't work;

```
.savilerowSelect .savilerowSelectInner,

.widgetSelect .widgetSelectInner {

width: 100%;

}
```

How can I make this filters one line?

Thank you.

Comment: The style attribute of the html element has a higher priority than css declarations, so try to add `!important` after your css rule: `width: 100% !important;`

Comment: @andreivictor Thank you it worked.